# Mouseleave event doesn't seem to work on closing sub menu in Typescript

Tags: javascript, css, typescript

I am trying to close a submenu with a "mouseleave" event however it does not seem to be working. Here's my code. It's driving me crazy :) I simply want the menu to close when you go outside of it. Part of the navigation with the menu is below.  Please let me know if you have any ideas. Thanks

```
const NavigationMenu = () => {
    const mobile_icon = document.getElementById("mobile-icon") as HTMLElement;
    const mobile_menu = document.getElementById("mobile-menu") as HTMLElement;
    const mobile_menu_bg = document.getElementById(
      "mobile-menu-background",
    ) as HTMLElement;
    const hamburger_icon = document.querySelector(
      "#mobile-icon i",
    ) as HTMLElement;
    const toggleDiscover = document.getElementById(
      "toggleDiscover",
    ) as HTMLElement;
    const toggleTools = document.getElementById("toggleTools") as HTMLElement;
    const nav_arrow_discover = document.querySelector(
      ".nav-arrow.discover",
    ) as HTMLElement;
    const nav_arrow_tools = document.querySelector(
      ".nav-arrow.tools",
    ) as HTMLElement;
    const discover = document.getElementById("discover") as HTMLElement;
    const tools = document.getElementById("tools") as HTMLElement;

    toggleDiscover.onclick = function () {
      discover.classList.toggle("show");
      nav_arrow_discover.classList.toggle("rotate");
    };

    toggleTools.onclick = function () {
      tools.classList.toggle("show");
      nav_arrow_tools.classList.toggle("rotate");
    };

    toggleDiscover.addEventListener("mouseleave", (event) => {
      tools.classList.toggle("show");
      console.log("firing"); /*this fires but it's not really working*/
    });

    function openCloseMenu(): void {
      mobile_menu.classList.toggle("block");
      mobile_menu.classList.toggle("active");
      mobile_menu_bg.classList.toggle("bg-black/60");
    }

    function changeIcon(): void {
      hamburger_icon.classList.toggle("fa-xmark");
    }

    mobile_icon.addEventListener("click", openCloseMenu);
    hamburger_icon.addEventListener("click", changeIcon);
 
};

export default NavigationMenu;
```

HTML

```
    <li class="mr-1 text-2xl hover:bg-gray-hover rounded-xl py-1">
            <span id="toggleDiscover">
              <a>Discover <i class="nav-arrow discover fa-solid fa-chevron-down fa-2xs ml-1  transition"></i></a>
            </span>

            <ul id="discover" class="first-letter:text-gray-800 w-full flex">
              <hr class="h-px mt-[1.5rem] w-full border-t-0.5 border-blue-dark relative" />
              <li class="mr-1 mt-0.5 text-2xl hover:bg-gray-hover rounded-xl hover:text-white py-1 flex items-center"><i class="fa-solid fa-house mr-0.75 ml-1.5"></i><.link navigate={~p"/discover?vertical=col-college-planning"} class="block text-2xl">College Planning</.link></li>
              <li class="mr-1 text-2xl hover:bg-gray-hover rounded-xl hover:text-white py-1 flex items-center"><i class="fa-regular fa-heart mr-1 ml-1.5"></i><.link navigate={~p"/discover?vertical=hsc-high-school"} class="block text-2xl">HS Success</.link></li>
              <li class="mr-1 text-2xl hover:bg-gray-hover rounded-xl hover:text-white py-1 flex items-center"><i class="fa-regular fa-heart mr-1 ml-1.5"></i><.link navigate={~p"/discover?vertical=careers"} class="block text-2xl">Careers</.link></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <!-- End Discover Dropdown -->
```

CSS

```
#discover {
  display: none;
}

#tools {
  display: none;
}

.nav-arrow.rotate {
  rotate: 180deg;
}

#discover.show,
#tools.show {
  display: block;
}

#discover.hide {
  display: none;
}
```